# Could a Ubuntu server log my activities (outside the console) through ssh?

Tags: server

For security reason, when i connect to an Ubuntu server through ssh, could the server log my keystrokes (pressed outside the console window) and view active processes or browser active tabs?

X11 forwarding is not enabled by default in Putty

Comment: When you press a key outside a window , that window will never get notified unless it registers a keylogger(which is not the case in a simple terminal window).And I think there's no problem unless there's an undiscovered vulnerability in SSH that can cause that.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. So, it is not possible to record pressed keys outside that putty terminal window? not even using the xinput command and associating event0 as a keyboard? Also is it possible to record the opened processes or browser tabs in the system ? @ParsaMousavi

Comment: All of them are possible if you use a malicious software , but PuTTY is both open-source and is trusted by the community.And from the security standpoint there should not be any problem as long as you know what you're doing and what software  you're using.

Comment: As malicious software you mean a software installed in my computer, right? But only using the terminal there is no way that the server could install any software in my computer to monitor my activities or record pressed keys outside of that window @ParsaMousavi

Comment: You're SSHing into the server,not server into your system.So the only thing you get from the server is the **STDOUT** and **STDERR** which means simply the output of the commands that run on the server.It cannot cause any harm to your system.(Unless causing a buffer overflow which I don't think to be the case in the new terminals).